# Trying to convert column currently from varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I been trying to alter this column but not having any luck. Have attached image below. I tried to run a convert currently from varchar to datetime but just keep getting date is out of range.

I have done the checks and seem to be fine. No issues with any broken data.

Is there anyone can help me what will convert this column, so it shows like the right image in the picture below (with the date and time).

It currently shows how it is with the left image but want it to look like the right image for the date column (2nd column)

http://postimg.org/image/64i4zw27x/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the date formats may be DD/MM/YYYY, so you may need to add a format specification.

Instead of

```
CONVERT(DateTime, @date)
```

try

```
CONVERT(DateTime, @date, 103)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx